# How to change font in class diagrams by tikz-uml?

Tags: tikz-uml

The doc of `tikz-uml` package says that the font size in diagrams could be changed by `\tikzumlset{font=\footnotesize}`, yet the font itself is not changed. I would like to change the font (in diagrams, not globally) from default style into mono style, say, monaco. Thanks!

BTW: I use `XeLaTeX` and `\setmonofont{Monaco}` to set global mono font.

Comment: `\tikzumlset{font=\footnotesize\ttfamily}` (leave out `\footnotesize` if the size change is not desired).

Comment: Welcome! Please provide everyone with a complete minimal example which can be compiled to illustrate the problem if @PaulGessler's suggestion does not solve the problem for you.

Comment: @PaulGessler's suggestion has solved my problem, many thanks! :) May I ask where to find documentations for such parameters (e.g. `\ttfamily` and others)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the font family command (here, `\ttfamily`) to the value of the `font` key along with the size command `\footnotesize`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\tikzumlset{font=\footnotesize\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\umlclass{Test}{n = 1;}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This solution is independent of how you select a particular monospaced font, whether by `fontspec` or by standard methods. `\ttfamily` will use whichever fixed-width font is selected by the rest of the code.

The reference page [LaTeX font commands](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rf10/pstex/latexcommands.htm) lists all available font commands for LaTeX. See the "activated by" column in the table there. In general, font families can be selected using a *switch* command that remains in effect for the entire group (such as `\ttfamily` here), or using a macro with an argument (such as `\texttt{<text>}`). In your use case, we use the switch command since TikZ will place these commands inside a group with the node contents.

Comment: If there is a definitive reference for the font family commands here on-site, please let me know about it. I searched to no avail, but it'd be better to have an on-site link if possible. I did not put the full list here because it's really an aside to the question at hand.

Comment: As a newbie, I have learned a lot from your answer, thanks again for your kind help! :)